# Ember type is undefined & error loading route with one-to-many association

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I've introduced a one-to-many association on to two models in my Ember app, and I am getting these rather cryptic errors:

```
[09:01:20.450] TypeError: type is undefined @ http://emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/getting-started/ember-data.js:2284
[09:01:20.444] DEPRECATION: Action handlers contained in an `events` object are deprecated in favor of putting them in an `actions` object (error on <Ember.Route:ember362>)
    trigger@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:29641
    handleError@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:29903
    invokeCallback@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:8055
    Promise.prototype.then/<@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:8109
    EventTarget.trigger@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:7878
    reject/<@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:8180
    DeferredActionQueues.prototype.flush@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5459
    Backburner.prototype.end@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5545
    Backburner.prototype.run@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5584
    executeTimers@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5807
    Backburner.prototype.setTimeout/laterTimer<@file:///home/zen/ember-project/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5666
[09:01:20.444] Error while loading route: (new TypeError("type is undefined", "http://emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/getting-started/ember-data.js", 2284))
```

I'm not exactly sure if I should be capitalising, camelcasing or lowercasing model names in `DS.belongsTo('modelName')` but I get this error when they're camelCased, other casing gets a 'model cannot be found' error so I figure this is the best error to get.

My Models and fixture data:

```
// Models

App.ServiceProvider = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    customers: DS.hasMany('customer')
});

App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
    serviceprovider: DS.belongsTo('serviceProvider'),
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string')
});

// Fixtures

App.ServiceProvider.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   name : "Some Org.",
   email : "admin@someorg.com.au",
   customers : [1, 2]
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name : "Some Co.",
   email : "admin@someco.com.au",
   customers : [3, 4]
 }
];

App.Customer.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   firstname : "John",
   lastname : "Smith",
   email : "admin@someorg.com.au",
   serviceprovider : [1]
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   firstname : "Jane",
   lastname : "Smith",
   email : "admin@someco.com.au",
   serviceprovider : [1]
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   firstname : "Jerry",
   lastname : "Smith",
   email : "admin@someco.com.au",
   serviceprovider : [2]
 },
 {
   id: 4,
   firstname : "Janet",
   lastname : "Smith",
   email : "admin@someco.com.au",
   serviceprovider : [2]
 }
];
```

I'm very new to Ember and any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, the problem was using an array for the id of a to-one relationship.

This was the problematic fixture

```
App.Customer.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   firstname : "John",
   lastname : "Smith",
   email : "admin@someorg.com.au",
   serviceprovider : [1]
 }
 ]
```

And this is the working one

```
 App.Customer.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   firstname : "John",
   lastname : "Smith",
   email : "admin@someorg.com.au",
   serviceprovider : 1
 }
 ]
```